# How can i get float values from audio being recorded by AVAudioRecorder?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiorecorder

I've built a UIView which draws a waveform through float values input. What I want my view to plot is the waveform of the audio recorded through mic input, while it's being recorded. I've looked into some frameworks, but i can't seem to find any which does this in the way I mention, and i'm getting some trouble with my implementation. I use:

```
audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(URL: soundURL, settings: settings)
audioRecorder.meteringEnabled = true
audioRecorder.recordForDuration(NSTimeInterval(20.0))
```

And then:

```
audioRecorder.updateMeters()
//this turns dBFS to a linear value from 0 to 1
let x = pow(10.0, ( Double(audioRecorder.peakPowerForChannel(0))/20 ))
//here I add the new meter value to my plotter view
waveForm.addnewValue(x)
```

As you can see in the link below, there are lots of plain areas, not only at the "clipping" area, but also at lower levels. I'm guessing this comes from the form in which `peakPowerForChannel()` returns its values in a "meter-like" way, smoothing all output.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuTCG.jpg

I don't like that way in which audio is being plotted, for I'd like to get something more like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSOtV.png

By getting actual float values for the samples being recorded, I suppose I can get actual values corresponding to each sample's amplitude, and get a result more similar to what I'm looking for.

Thanks for your help!

---

After implementing a dispatch timer as suggested by Rob Napier, and changing the divisor in my dBFS to linear conversion, the only thing I got is a more vertically-compressed waveform, not achieving at all the effect i truly need for my view (see link above).

There are still plain areas at different points and a sort of running average seems to affect the waveform as it transits from sound to silence.

This is my current code:

```
var dTimer: DispatchTimer!

dTimer = DispatchTimer(seconds: 0.1) {
  self.audioRecorder.updateMeters()
  let x = pow(10.0, (Double(self.audioRecorder.peakPowerForChannel(0))/50))
  self.waveForm.addnewValue(x)
}
```

The question is: Is there a way to get the values being recorded by AVAudioRecorder, so I can set those values as the values for my waveform plotter?

Comment: Look at `averagePower` rather than `peakPower`. You probably don't want to try to work with 20-40k samples per second (and handle the data in real-time to avoid interfering with the recording) just to draw mildly-informative curves. If you really do, you'll likely need to move down to Core Audio rather than using high-level interfaces like AVAudioRecorder. How often are you calling `updateMeters`? You may be calling too often or not often enough (or not consistently).

Comment: I've already used `averagePower`, but results are very much similar. I call `audioRecorder.updateMeters()`, `let x = pow(10.0, ( Double(audioRecorder.peakPowerForChannel(0))/20 ))` and  `waveForm.addnewValue(x)`  every 0.1 secs, only 10 times per second

Comment: What are you using to keep time? `NSTimer` doesn't promise very high accuracy for example. Are you checking what time it actually is and adjusting your x-value to match? (and that'll also let you know if you're drifting.) I'd also look at a faster sample rate. 10Hz may be too slow to get the graph you want. And you're clipping a lot, so I'd check your outputs and make sure they're actually in the range 0-1 (is peakPower really 0 that often?)

Comment: I actually use `NSTimer`. Do you mean sample rate for plotting or actual audio sample rate? The lots of clipping come from the fact that my plot is so insensitive that i need to make loud noises for it to register noticeable change in waveform amplitude...

Comment: I mean how often your timer fires. And if you're having a gain problem, don't divide by 20. Divide by 40 or 80 (or multiply the final result by something). You control your scale. Technically multiplying is a bit more accurate but adjusting your log/linear conversion may actually scale much more to your liking.

Comment: Ok, so i could change NSTimer update rate to 0.0001? the division by 20 is to convert the logarithmic dB scale (-inf to 0) into a linear (0.0 to 1.0) scale. gain is not a problem, but the representation of actual sound coming into the plotter...

Comment: Don't try to use an NSTimer that fast. You'd want a dispatch timer IMO. If you change the division from 20 to something else, you'll still get 0-1, just at a different scaling.

Comment: is `let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.0001 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
            dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.trackRecording()
            }` a good approach as the dispatch timer you mention?

Comment: It's hard to believe you need that kind of granularity, but it's reasonably good. You can get better repeating timers using a timer source. See https://github.com/rnapier/RNTimer/blob/master/RNTimer/RNTimer.m for an example.

Comment: how can i get this dispatch timer to loop or repeat? will it do it by itself?

Comment: The RNTimer code is documented here: https://github.com/rnapier/RNTimer. It's a repeating timer (there's no need for this much code for a non-repeating timer).

Comment: Thanks,  I've implemented it already,  the thing is my problem remains the same.. (see edited post)